# CSS select all elements except h1

Tags: css

Is it possible to do with CSS something like this:

CSS:

```
#right div.item-page, #right .newsflashlatest_news {
    padding: 0 133px 0 50px;
    text-align: justify;
}

#right .item-page h1, #right .newsflashlatest_news h1 {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

#right {
    float: left;
    width: 755px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="right">
fsfds

<div class="item-page" style="background: blue;">
<h1>Home</h1>
<p>Pri iisque malorum ei, est te suavitate mediocritatem, facer molestie explicari vix ne. </p>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to apply the rules above to all elements in div.itemp-page except h1 element. Basically this means that all elements would have padding except h1 element.

Simply adding "#right div.item-page h1" somehow doesn't work for my case (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pr47M/)

Comment: Try `#right div.item-page :not(h1){}`.

Comment: This will add padding also to all subelements in any level of div.item-page (like div.item-page div div will also receive padding, I do not need this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
#right div.item-page {
     padding: 0 133px 0 50px;  
     text-align:justify;
}
#right div.item-page h1 {
     padding: 0;  
     text-align:left;
}
```

Alternatively you can also do this

```
#right div.item-page *:not(h1) {
     padding: 0 133px 0 50px;  
     text-align:justify;
}
```

Comment: Actually I thought it works, but it doens't. Because it will add padding to the subelement of div.item-page (for example to <div id="subdiv1">), but it would also add padding to all subelements (all children) as well (like <div id="subdiv1"><div id="subdiv2">... then subdiv2 will also receive padding, but it is not required). The first option with padding: 0 doesn't work for me wither). (http://tax.allfaces.lv/)

Answer (score 4):

According to your jsfiddle change the css with following code...

```
#right div.item-page *:not(h1), #right .newsflashlatest_news *:not(h1) {
   padding: 0 133px 0 50px;
   text-align: justify;
}

#right .item-page h1, #right .newsflashlatest_news h1 {
   padding: 0 !important;
}

#right {
   float: left;
   width: 755px;
}
```

problem solved. :)

Answer (score 3):

Why dont just write -

```
#right div.item-page {
     padding: 0 133px 0 50px;  
     text-align:justify;
}
#right div.item-page h1 {
     padding: 0px;  
     text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seriously, this many answers, and not this one...?

```
#right div.item-page *:not(h1) {
     padding: 0 133px 0 50px;  
     text-align:justify;
}
```

This **exactly** answers your question, but you should *never ever* use a `*` selector, very bad practice for performance and maintainability. Instead you should style elements correctly on their own, and avoid overly generic styling.

Comment: Nobody heard of CSS3 obviously :)
Just a question, why use `*` ? Wouldn't work without it eather ?

Comment: It will work the same without it, I added it to be verbose about that it implies the `*` selector. Because CSS is evaluated back to front this is a computationally very expensive rule for the browser - it has to evaluate it for every element on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#right div.item-page {
     padding: 0 133px 0 50px;  
     text-align:justify;
}
#right div.item-page h1
{
padding:0px;
}
```

There is no specific CSS selector that leaves a particular element out. You have to manually add it. Any element that is specified by tag and class automatically overrides just a class. Read more about CSS classes [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#right div.item-page *{
    padding-bottom:20px;    
}
#right div.item-page h1{
    padding-bottom:0;   
}
```

'*' represent all elements inside the div

Answer (score 0):

can you not just do something like

```
#right div.item-page h1{
  padding: 0px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use your class but add also this at the bottom:

```
#right div.item-page h1 {
 padding: 0;  
 text-align:whatever-you-need;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is no css selector that excludes a particular element out of the selection.
So you can use your selector, but you do have to add i.e.

```
#right div.item-page {
     padding: 0 133px 0 50px;  
     text-align:justify;
}
#right div.item-page h1{
padding: 0;
}
```