# CSS: selecting every div element except for one

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with the ':not' selector in CSS, I want to select everything under head except for the title (h1) I tried using '#head:not(h1)' but it still selects everything under #head. What is the proper way to select all but h1? Thankyou.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
    /*I want to select all the elements under head id except for h1 title*/
    #head:not(h1){
        background: red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "subpage">
    <div id = "head">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>My Webpage</h1>
            <h3>Subheading</h3>
        </hgroup>

        <div class = "posts">
            <ul id = "post1">
                <li>entered by: John</li>
                <li>hearts: 2000</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class = "posts">
            <ul id = "post2">
                <li>entered by: Chris</li>
                <li>hearts: 100</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "whats new">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>a bunch of text</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your current CSS selector only targets the element with the ID `head`, not the children of the element as you intended - consider adding a space between `#head` and `:not(h1)` (i.e. the [descendent combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)) to fix the problem.

Comment: I'm confused about how "selecting every div element except for one" correlates with selecting everything but a `h1` tag

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
#head *:not(h1) {
    background: red;
}
```

OR

```
#head :not(h1) {
    background: red;
}
```

However, meaning that it selects everything except 'h1' under '#head' means that it contains 'hgroup', which is the parent element of 'h1'.

In this case, the background color of 'h1' is 'transparent' by default, so the background color is red due to 'hgroup'.

```css
#head *:not(h1) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="subpage">
    <div id="head">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>My Webpage</h1>
            <h3>Subheading</h3>
        </hgroup>

        <div class="posts">
            <ul id="post1">
                <li>entered by: John</li>
                <li>hearts: 2000</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="posts">
            <ul id="post2">
                <li>entered by: Chris</li>
                <li>hearts: 100</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="whats new">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>a bunch of text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the suggestion, I tried following this but for some reason, no background colour is showing up.

Comment: @LeilaK. try putting a `!important` tag on the end

Answer (score 0):

You could separately specify the `h1` elements to have the base color.

```css
#head h1 {
    background: white;
}
#head * {  /* depending on the look you want, you may not need the * */
    background: red; 
}
```

```html
<div id = "subpage">
    <div id = "head">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>My Webpage</h1>
            <h3>Subheading</h3>
        </hgroup>

        <div class = "posts">
            <ul id = "post1">
                <li>entered by: John</li>
                <li>hearts: 2000</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class = "posts">
            <ul id = "post2">
                <li>entered by: Chris</li>
                <li>hearts: 100</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "whats new">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>a bunch of text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#subpage div.head *:not(h1) {
     background: red;
}
```

use styles like this.

go to this link & you can get idea
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16769552/8928037

Answer (score 0):

First you want to add a background color for `<h1>`. Try this.

```css
#head h1{
    background: white;
}

#head :not(h1) {
    background: red ;
}
```

```html
<div id = "subpage">
    <div id = "head">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>My Webpage</h1>
            <h3>Subheading</h3>
        </hgroup>

        <div class = "posts">
            <ul id = "post1">
                <li>entered by: John</li>
                <li>hearts: 2000</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class = "posts">
            <ul id = "post2">
                <li>entered by: Chris</li>
                <li>hearts: 100</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "whats new">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>a bunch of text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```